# How should I use dependencies of dependencies?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm working on project using warp. Warp includes the bytes cargo as a dependency and I want to use the Bytes struct that gets passed into the callback. Here's an example:

```
use warp::Filter;

fn process(data: bytes::Bytes) -> impl warp::reply::Reply {
    println!("{:?}", data);
    "processed!"
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let process = warp::path("process")
        .and(warp::post())
        .and(warp::body::bytes())
        .map(process);

    warp::serve(process)
        .run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3030))
        .await;
}
```

Here's the dependencies in my Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
bytes = "*"
tokio = { version = "0.2", features = ["full"] }
warp = "0.2"
```

This setup gives me this error:

```
error[E0631]: type mismatch in function arguments
  --> src/main.rs:13:14
   |
3  | fn process(data: bytes::Bytes) -> impl warp::reply::Reply {
   | --------------------------------------------------------- found signature of `fn(bytes::bytes::Bytes) -> _`
...
13 |         .map(process);
   |              ^^^^^^^ expected signature of `fn(bytes::bytes::Bytes) -> _`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `warp::generic::Func<(bytes::bytes::Bytes,)>` for `fn(bytes::bytes::Bytes) -> impl warp::reply::Reply {process}`
```

Not a big fan of this error message because it's telling me that it's looking for the signature `fn(bytes::bytes::Bytes) -> _` and it found `fn(bytes::bytes::Bytes) -> _` which pretty much look exactly the same to me, but after some searching I realized it's because there's two different versions of Bytes getting pulled in, so I adjust my Cargo.toml like this:

```
bytes = "0.5.6"
```

So I get the same version of bytes that warp is pulling in.

Is this the conventional way to deal with this issue?

Comment: Just for info, this was caused because bytes just released `0.6.0` with breaking changes.

Comment: There isn't really a way to select a version based on a transitive dependency - you just have to look at what version the dependency uses and replicate that in your crate's dependency list. However, if you specify the version of the transitive dependency, cargo will only allow using newer versions if they're compatible according to semantic versioning. This should protect you from unexpected breakages when one of the dependencies releases a new version - but to benefit from this you can't use `dep = "*"`.

Comment: Ideally Warp would re-export the `bytes` crate at its crate root. You could file an issue or open a PR to add this.

Comment: @KaiJ, Is re-xporting like that common practice?

Comment: It's fairly common. RustCrypto's crates use it extensively and Hyper reexports http at its crate root

Answer (score -1):

It seems that, the issue you're encountering stems from a type incompatibility due to Rust's dependency management system of Cargo, pulling in two distinct versions of the bytes library. When you specify bytes = "*" in your Cargo.toml, Cargo attempts to fetch the latest version of the bytes library. However, warp might rely on a specific version of the bytes library.

The standard approach to address this discrepancy is to ensure that both your project and its dependencies are aligned to use the same version of the library. You can ascertain the exact version being used by inspecting the Cargo.lock file or by directly examining the Cargo.toml of the libraries you depend on.

For instance, if you determine that warp utilizes version 0.5.6 of bytes, it's prudent to specify that exact version in your Cargo.toml to maintain consistency and avoid type mismatches.

Comment: This repeats the information in the question without adding anything.